# Efficient way to detect adjacent players in turn based game

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I am creating a turn-based game, so far players can move on their turn and pick up weapons( currently visualization is not great, but player damage is manipulated). I am using canvas api for graphics. Players move on arrow keys.

Now the next step is to check if the player moved in adjacent cells so I can start the fight. 
Two approaches come to my mind.

1. Save an array of indexes of those cells that are currently on four
   sides of the player and update it on every move. For example, if
   player is on [1,2], then his array would be
   [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,1],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3]]. But as you can see
   updated it on every move would be a complete mess.
2. Loop over each cell on four sides to check if the other is in one of
   them. That too would require a lot of code.

Is there any simple and efficient way to solve this problem?
 [game link](https://hassanraja447.github.io/offensive-strike/)

Comment: I think the 2nd approach is better. You can check if they have neighbor cells in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, since your game is tile-based, this could be pretty easy: you can check the distance in tiles. 
Let's say that the two players being close enough means that they are on adjacent tiles (I included diagonals but do as you wish of course):

```
+--+---+---+---+--+
|  |   |   |   |  |
+--+---+---+---+--+
|  | x | x | x |  |
+--+---+---+---+--+
|  | x | O | x |  |   All the X are adjacent to O
+--+---+---+---+--+
|  | x | x | x |  |
+--+---+---+---+--+
|  |   |   |   |  |
+--+---+---+---+--+
```

Let's call `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` the respective coordinates of `player1` and `player2`. All you have to check is that the difference between `x1` and `x2` and the difference between `y1` and `y2` doesn't exceed 1 (tile, that's why I write `* tileSize` in the code). `0` means *overlap*. `1` means *adjacent*. `2` means *far*.

Here's an example:

```js
const KEY_LEFT = 37;
const KEY_RIGHT = 39;
const KEY_UP = 38;
const KEY_DOWN = 40;

let canvas, ctx, closeText;

let playerTurn = 1;
let player1, player2;

let tileSize;

init();

function init() {
 canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  closeText = document.getElementById('close');
  
  tileSize = canvas.width / 10;
  
  player1 = new Player(10, 20, 'red');
  player2 = new Player(50, 40, 'green');
  
  updateText(areClose(player1, player2));
  
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#888';

 window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp, false);
  
  draw();
}

function onKeyUp(e) {
 let dx = 0, dy = 0;

 // Where does the player move
 switch (e.keyCode) {
   case KEY_LEFT: dx -= tileSize; break;
   case KEY_RIGHT: dx += tileSize; break;
   case KEY_UP: dy -= tileSize; break;
   case KEY_DOWN: dy += tileSize; break;
  }
  
  // Which player moves
  if (playerTurn === 1) {
   player1.x += dx;
    player1.y += dy;
  } else if (playerTurn === -1) {
   player2.x += dx;
    player2.y += dy;
  }
  
  // Change player
  playerTurn *= -1;
  
  // Are they close enough to fight?
  const close = areClose(player1, player2);
  updateText(close);
  
  // Redraw the board and the players
  draw();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBoard();
  drawPlayer(player1);
  drawPlayer(player2);
}

function drawBoard() {
  // Horizontal lines
 for (let i = tileSize; i < canvas.width; i += tileSize) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(i, canvas.height);
    ctx.closePath();
   ctx.stroke();
  }
  // Vertical lines
  for (let j = tileSize; j < canvas.height; j += tileSize) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, j);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, j);
    ctx.closePath();
   ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function drawPlayer(player) {
 ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.size, player.size);
}

function Player(x, y, color) {
 this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.color = color;
  this.size = 10;
}

function areClose(a, b) {
 return Math.abs(a.x - b.x) < 2 * tileSize && Math.abs(a.y - b.y) < 2 * tileSize;
}

function updateText(close) {
 closeText.innerText = close ? 'Close' : 'Not close';
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
<p id="close"></p>
```